# Galois Groups of a family of polynomials

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, galois-groups

I've stumbled across the family of polynomials
$ f_p(x) = x^{p-1} + 2 x^{p-2} + \cdots + (p-1) x + p $,
where $p$ is an odd prime.  It's not too hard to show that $f_p(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ -- look at the Newton polygon of $f_p(x+1)$ over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and you see that it factors as the product of an irreducible polynomial of degree $p-2$ and a linear.  Since $f_p(x)$ has no real roots (look at the derivative of $f_p(x) (x-1)^2$) it must be irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.  It's also not hard to see that the only primes dividing the discriminant are $2, p$ and primes dividing $p+1$.  I would expect that the Galois group of a randomish polynomial would be the full symmetric group.  Indeed, according to Magma this is true for $f_p(x)$ for $p=3,5, \dots, 61$ with the exception of $p=7,17$.  So my question is -- are these the only exceptions?

Added later: I've had Magma find the Galois group for primes through 101 and it found another exception: $p=97$.  So my initial guess was wrong.

Another addition: If one looks at odd $p$ (not just prime) for $p < 100$ there is another exception, 49.  Also 241 is  <strike>not</strike>  an exception (misread magma's output).

The ideas in the following two papers may be of help:

"On the Galois Groups of the exponential Taylor polynomials" by Robert Coleman, in L'Enseignement Mathematique, v 33 (1987) pp 183-189

and

"On the Galois Group of generalized Laguerre polynomials" by Farshid Hajir, J. Th´eor. Nombres Bordeaux 17 (2005), no. 2, 517–525 (also available on the author's web page).

Comment: Is there any reason not to expand your search to non-prime p? That would at least give us more data.

Comment: Your three exceptions 7, 17, 97 are the first three primes of the form 2*q^2-1 where q is prime, which is sequence A092057. Is the next exception 241?

Comment: @David, I can do more calculations.  I'm not sure that $f_n(x)$ is irreducible for non-prime $n$ (at least my proof of irreducibility doesn't work).

@tdnoe: I'm trying the calculation for 241 now, but this may stress Magma to the limit!

Comment: Just calculate the discriminant - it is a square, and in fact, a square for all the discriminants in the series. Clearly we just need a nice closed form for the discriminant that is probably of the form a square times 2*q^2-1

Comment: It seems to be true for all odd numbers of the form 2*n^2-1

Comment: Magma says that $7,17,49$ and $97$ are the only odd exceptions below 100.

Comment: Mathematica claims that the discriminant for 241 is a perfect square. The square root in question has 569 digits, so it won't fit in a comment box, but I can post it if anyone wants to see it.

Comment: We have either discovered a bug in Magma or Mathematica here. I vote that Mathematica is right, because computing a discriminant is a much less error prone operation than computing the full Galois group.

Comment: For 241, the discriminant is 2^240 11^478 241^238 -- clearly a square.

Comment: @David Speyer: sage says that the discriminant for 241 is

$2^{240} 11^{478} 241^{238}$

Comment: I don't get your proof of the irreducibility: over $\mathbb{Q}_p$, the Newton polygon only tells you that the polynomial has a linear factor, but it doesn't give a criterion for irreducibility.

Comment: @Homology: in any case, irreducibility follows by the ideas described in the comments to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/18094/polynomial-with-the-primes-as-coefficients-irreducible/ .

Comment: @Homology: the slope of the segment in the Newton polygon is $-1/(p-2)$ so that every root of the factor corresponding to that has additive valuation $1/(p-2)$.  So the ramification index of the extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ generated by a root is $p-2$ which is also the degree of the polynomial.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let $\alpha$ be a root of  a polynomial 
$f(x) \in \mathbf{Q}[x]$ of degree $n$, let $K = \mathbf{Q}(\alpha)$,
$L$ be the Galois closure of $K$, and 
$G = \mathrm{Gal}(L/\mathbf{Q}) \subset S_n$.
How does one prove that a permutation group contains $A_n$?
Following Jordan, the usual method is to show that it
is sufficiently highly transitive. Also following Jordan, 
to do this it suffices to construct subgroups of $G$ which
act faithfully and transitively on $n-k$ points and trivially
on the other $k$ points (for $k$ large, $\ge 6$ using CFSG), and
to show that $G$ is primitive. (The standard method for doing this is 
to find $l$-cycles for a prime $l$.)
In the context of a Galois group, the most obvious place
to look for "elements" is to consider the decomposition
groups $D$ at places of $\mathbf{Q}$.
If $l$ is unramified in $K$, this corresponds to looking
at a Frobenius element (conjugacy class). In practice
(as far as a computation goes) this is quite useful,
but theoretically it is not so great unless there is a
prime $l$ for which the factorization is particularly clean.
This leaves the places which ramify in $L$.
For example, if $v = \infty$, one is considering
the action of complex conjugation; if there are exactly
two complex roots then $c$ is a $2$-cycle, and from Jordan's
theorem (easy in this case) we see that if $G$ is primitive
then $G$ is $S_n$.

The proposed method (following Coleman et. al.) for proving that
$G$ contains $A_n$ is somewhat misguided, I think. The
key point about the polynomial
$\sum_{k=0}^{n} x^k/k!$ is that the corresponding field is ramified at many primes,
and the decomposition groups at these primes give the
requisite elements. Conversely, the polynomial considered in this
problem corresponds to a field with somewhat limited ramification
- as has been noted, the only primes which ramify divide
$p(p+1)$.

It can be hard to compute Galois groups of random families of polynomials in general. I do not know if this is true in the present case, but given the lack of motivation I won't spend any more time thinking about it than the last hour or two, and instead  give some partial results. However, the methods
given here may well apply more generally.
Let $n = p - 1$.

CLAIM: Suppose that $p+1$ is exactly divisible by a prime $l > 3$.
Then $G$ contains $A_{n}$. (This applies to a set $p$
of relative density one inside the primes.)

STEP I: Factorization of $p$; $G$ is primitive.
Let $f(x) = x^{p-1} + 2 x^{p-2} +  \ldots + p$. 
Note that
$$(x-1)^2 f(x) = x(x^{p} - 1) - p(x-1) = x^{p+1} - 1 - (p+1)(x-1).$$
We deduce that
$f(x) \equiv x(x-1)^{p-2} \mod p$, and that
$$p = \mathfrak{p} \mathfrak{q}^{p-2}$$
for primes $\mathfrak{p}$ and $\mathfrak{q}$ in
the ring of integers $O_K$ of $K$ both of norm $p$.
(To show this one needs to check that $[O_K:\mathbf{Z}[\alpha]]$
is co-prime to $p$ - one can do this by considering the Newton
Polygon of $f(x+1)$.)
Let $D \subset G$ be a decomposition
group at $p$. This corresponds
to choosing a simultaneous embedding of the roots
of $f(x)$ into an algebraic closure of the $p$-adic numbers.
We see that we may write
$f(x) = a(x) b(x)$ as polynomials over the $p$-adic numbers (which
I can't latex at this point for some reason),
 where $a(x) \equiv x \mod p$
has degree one and $b(x) \equiv (x-1)^{p-2}$ is
irreducible of degree $p-2$ and
corresponds to a totally ramified extension.
Clearly $D$ acts transitively on the $p-2 = n-1$ roots of $b(x)$ and fixes
the roots of $a(x)$. Since $D \subset G \cap S_{n-1}$, we
see that $G \cap S_{n-1}$ is transitive in $S_{n-1}$ and
so $G$ is $2$-transitive (and hence primitive).

Step II: Factorization of $l$:
Let $l$ be a prime dividing $p+1$. We
assume that $l \ge 5$ and $l$ exactly divides $p+1$.
We see that
$$f(x) \equiv (x-1)^{l-2} \prod_{i=1}^{k-1} (x-\zeta^i)^{l}$$
where $\zeta$ is a $k$th root of unity and $kl=p+1$.
This suggests that:
$$l = \mathfrak{p}^{l-2} \prod_{i=1}^{k} \mathfrak{q}^l.$$
This also follows from a Newton polygon argument applied
to $f(x - \zeta^i)$. (Warning, this uses that $l$ exactly divides $p+1$.)

Step III: Some basic facts about local extensions:

Lemma 1. Suppose the ramification degree of $E/\mathbb{Q}_l$ 
is $l^m$. Then the ramification degree of the Galois
closure of $E$ is only divisible by primes dividing $l(l^m-1)$.
Proof. Kummer Theory.

Lemma 2. Suppose that $h(x) \in \mathbf{Q}_l[x]$
is an irreducible polynomial of degree $k$ with $(k,l) = 1$,
such that the 
corresponding field $E/\mathbf{Q}_l$ is totally ramified.
If $F$ is the splitting field of $h(x)$, then
$\mathrm{Gal}(F/\mathbf{Q}_l) \subset S_k$ contains a $k$-cycle.
Proof: From a classification of tamely ramified extensions, there
exists an unramified extension $A$ such that $[EA:A] = [E:\mathbf{Q}_l]$
and $EA/A$ is cyclic and Galois. It follows that 
$\mathrm{Gal}(EA/A)$ acts transitively and faithfully on the roots
of $h(x)$, and is thus generated by a $k$-cycle.

Step IV: $G$ contains an $l-2$-cycle.
Consider the decomposition group $D$ at $l$.
The orbits of $D$ correspond to the factorization of $l$ in $O_K$.
On the factors corresponding to primes of the form 
$\mathfrak{q}^p_i$, the image of $D$ factors through a group
whose inertia has degree divisible only by primes dividing
$l(l-1)$, by Lemma 1. On the other hand, on
the factor corresponding to $\mathfrak{p}^{l-2}$, the image of
inertia contains an $l-2$ cycle, by Lemma 2.
 Since $(l(l-1),l-2) = 1$, we see
that $D \subset G$ contains an $l-2$ cycle.

Step V: Jordan's Theorem. 
Since $G$ is primitive, and $G$ contains a subgroup
that acts transitively and faithfully on $l-2$ points
(and trivially on all other points), we deduce
(from the standard proof of Jordan's theorem)
that $G$ is $n-(l-2)+1 = n+3-l$ transitive. This is at least $6$
(since $n+2$ is at least $2l$)
and so $G$ contains $A_n$ (by CFSG).

STEP VI: (for you, dear reader)
Find the analogous argument when $p+1$ is exactly divisible
by $l^k$ for some $k \ge 2$ --- try to construct a cycle
of degree $l^k - 2$, although be careful as it will no
longer be the case (as it was above) that
$[O_K:\mathbf{Z}[\alpha]]$ was co-prime to $l$.
This still leaves $p-1$ either a power of $2$ or a power
of $2$ times $3$, which might be annoying --- one would
have to think hard about the structure of the decomposition group at $2$ in those cases.

Comment: Terrific!  It's amusing that we need CFSG.

Comment: Here's some speculation: If $g_n(x) = x^{n-1} f_n(1/x)$ then $x g_n(x)$ is a truncated version of $\log(1-x)$.  Is there a connection with Coleman's (and Schur's) truncated exponential polynomials?

Comment: I had Magma calculate the galois group for $p=127$ (so all the non-$p$ ramification would be at 2) but it was still the full symmetric group.

Comment: I believe the standard result of Jordan that you refer to assumes that the action is *primitive* on $l-2$ points (and trivial on the rest), which is not guaranteed by an $(l-2)$-cycle, unless $l-2$ is prime. However, since $l-2 < (p-1)/2$ a theorem of Marggraff (1889, see Dixon-Mortimer's GTM 7.4B) shows that $G$ nevertheless contains $A_n$. So I guess this means CFSG is not actually necessary!

Comment: I only know how to prove Lemma 1 when $m = 1$ and $E/\mathbb{Q}_l$ is totally ramified. This is all that is needed. How is it proved in general (if it is true)?

Answer (score 10):

The following proves David's statement on the discriminant.

$f_n(x) := x^{n-1}\ +\ 2x^{n-2}\ +\ ...\ +\ n$

$f_n(x) = x\frac{x^n-1}{(x-1)^2}-\frac{n}{x-1}$

Say $f_n(\alpha)=0$,

$f'_n(x) = \frac{x^n-1}{(x-1)^2} + x\frac{nx^{n-1}(x-1)^2-2(x-1)(x^n-1)}{(x-1)^4}+\frac{n}{(x-1)^2}$

$f'_n(\alpha) = \frac{n}{\alpha(\alpha-1)}+(n(\frac{n}{\alpha(\alpha-1)}+\frac{1}{(\alpha-1)^2})-\frac{2\alpha}{\alpha-1}\frac{n}{\alpha(\alpha-1)})+\frac{n}{(\alpha-1)^2}$

$=\frac{n}{\alpha(\alpha-1)^2}((\alpha-1)+(n(\alpha-1)+\alpha)-2\alpha+\alpha)$

$=\frac{n(n+1)(\alpha-1)}{\alpha(\alpha-1)^2}=\frac{n(n+1)}{\alpha(\alpha-1)}$

$\Delta_{f_n} = (-1)^{\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}} \text{Nm}(f'_n(\alpha)) = (-1)^{\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}}\frac{(n(n+1))^{n-1}}{nf(1)} = (-1)^{\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}}2n^{n-3}(n+1)^{n-2}$

This shows that whenever $n+1$ is twice an odd square the discriminant is a square.

Comment: Very nice  I was doing the same calculation in my head while driving home (probably not too safe).  This combined with a remark in the two papers that I cited (which needs to be checked) about the lcm of the denominators of the slopes of all the segments in all Newton Polygons -- to the effect that if that lcm is divisible by a prime > n/2 then the galois group contains $A_n$ should finish it off.

Comment: One more thing: the galois group of $f_7(x)$ is strictly contained in $A_6$.  In fact it has order 120.

Comment: I am confused.  As A_6 is simple of order 360, it cannot have a subgroup of order 120, as this would give a nontrivial homomorphism to S_3.

Comment: My proof was slightly different: Let $g_n(x)=(x−1)2f_n(x)=(x_n+1−x)−n(x−1)$. By differentiating and dividing by $(x−1)$ you get $2f_n(x)+(x−1)f_n′(x)=(n+1)(x^n−1)/(x−1)$. So Res$((x−1)f_n′(x))= $Res$((n+1)(x^n-1)/(x-1))$ ,which by one of the definitions of the resultant yields $(-1)^{n-1} (n+1)^{n-1} n^{n-2}$. Switching the order and attaching the $(-1)^{(n-1)(n-2)/2}$ for the discriminant and then dividing by $f_n(1)$ to get rid of the effect of $(x−1)$ gets the answer. – Victor Miller 0 secs ago 


Comment: Victor, your "remark which needs to be checked" sounds quite similar to a theorem on conditions which guarantee a transitive subgroup of S_n is either S_n or A_n. See Theorems 2.1 and 2.2 at www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/galoisSnAn.pdf

Comment: @KConrad: Coleman cites a theorem of Camille Jordan which says that if $G$ is a transitive subgroup of $S_n$  which contains a $p$-cycle for some prime $p$ strictly between $n/2$ and $n-2$ then $G$ contains $A_n$.  Coleman and Hajir both exploit this.  Hajir points out that to find such a $p$ one need only find one which divides the denominator of some slope in any Newton Polygon.  For the Laguerre polynomials he can always find this (with a small number of exceptions).  I've been checking that criterion with these polynomials and it doesn't happen very often.

Comment: @John Shareshian: I erred.  The Galois group is of order 120, but it's not contained in $A_n$ since the discriminant is $-1$ times a square in that case.  According to magma it's generated by the permutations $(1,5)(2,6)(3,4)$ and $(1,4,5,3,2,6)$.

Comment: The Newton Polygons of these polynomials are relatively easy to study, and by some inspection, proving the assertion needed, prime > n/2, seems quite hard... These are just my calculations on page. Someone else confirm

Answer (score 6):

The discriminant of this polynomial is $(-1)^{\binom{p}{2}} 2 p^{p-3} (p+1)^{p-2}$. Thus, whenever $p$ is of the form $2k^2-1$ with $k$ odd, the discriminant will be a perfect square and the Galois group will be a subgroup of the alternating group. That explains all the counterexamples we have found. We now verify that this is the discriminant.

---

I'm finding signs difficult tonight, so I'll only get my formulas right up to a sign.

We start with the following observation. Let $f$ be a polynomial of degree $n$. Then $$\mathrm{Disc} ( f(x) (x-1)) = f(1)^2 \mathrm{Disc} (f(x)) \quad (*)$$
To see this, let $r_1$, $r_2$, ..., $r_n$ be the roots of the polynomial $f$ and remember that $\mathrm{Disc}(f) = \prod_{i < j} (r_i-r_j)^2.$

Now, recall the identity
$$\mathrm{Disc}(x^{n+1}-ax+b) = \left( (n+1)^{n+1} b^n - n^n a^{n+1} \right).$$
It is easy to check that the right hand side vanishes if and only if $x^{n+1}-ax+b$ has a root in common with its derivative $(n+1)x^n-a$, so the two sides agree up to a constant. Checking the constant is left as an exercise.

Plugging in $a=b+1$, we get
$$\mathrm{Disc}(x^{n+1}-(b+1)x+b) = \left( (n+1)^{n+1} b^n - n^n (b+1)^{n+1} \right).$$
Applying $(*)$ to the identity $x^{n+1}-(b+1)x+b = (x-1)(x^n+x^{n-1}+\cdots+x^2+x-b)$, we get
$$\mathrm{Disc}(x^n+x^{n-1}+\cdots+x^2+x-b) = \frac{ (n+1)^{n+1} b^n - n^n (b+1)^{n+1} }{(n-b)^2}.$$

Taking the limit as $b \to n$, and using l'Hospital twice, we get
$$\mathrm{Disc}(x^n+x^{n-1}+\cdots+x^2+x-n) =$$
$$ (-1)^{\binom{n+1}{2}} \frac{ (n+1)^{n+1} n (n-1) n^{n-2} - n^n (n+1) n (n+1)^{n-1} }{2}$$
$$=  \frac{ (n+1)^n n^{n-1} \left( (n+1)(n-1) - n^2 \right)   }{2} =  \frac{ (n+1)^n n^{n-1}  }{2}$$

Now, applying $(*)$ once more, we get
$$\mathrm{Disc}(x^{n-1} + 2 x^{n-2} + \cdots + (n-1) x + n )$$
$$ \frac{ (n+1)^n n^{n-1}  }{2} \ \left( \frac{n(n+1)}{2} \right)^{-2} = 2 (n+1)^{n-2} n^{n-3}.$$

Comment: Observe that $(x-1)^2 f_n(x) = x^{n+1} - x - n(x-1)$ so the derivative is $(n+1)(x^n-1)$.  If $q$ is prime then the only way that both can vanish over $\mathbb{F}_{q^k}$ is if $x=1$.  But $f_n(1) = n(n+1)/2$, so the primes dividing the discriminant must divide $n(n+1)$.

Comment: "If q is prime then the only way that both can vanish over $F_{q^k}$ is if $x=1$". Or if $q$ divides $n$ and $x$ is zero. But in that case we also have $q|n(n+1)$, so your final conclusion is correct. 

Comment: @David, thanks for catching that.  I'll redo the calculation, but magma reports that $f_{71}$ has galois group the full symmetric group so the discriminant would have to be negative.

Comment: Also, the $p^{p-3}$ part comes from looking at the Newton polygon.

Comment: @Victor: 71 is 3 mod 4, which is in accordance with the sign pattern above.